# How to add Euro as Currency Sign in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I want to create a report which will display Euro/Pound/INR Sign in front of the value. 
But as per my current Crystal Report setup I can only add Dollar Sign as currency Symbol.

I want to create report where I will be converting currencies from Dollar to Euro/Pound/INR/... So I want code that will dynamically add the currency symbols.

So can anybody help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right click, choose Format Field...
- Select the Number tab, click the Customize... button
- Select the Currency Symbol tab
- Select the Enable Currency Symbol checkbox
- Type the Euro symbol (€) into the Currency Symbol box

** edit **

If you need more flexibility, you can add a custom formula to the currency symbol:

```
Select {table.currency_code}
Case "USD","CAD": "$"
Case "EUR": "€"
Case "GBP": "£"
// todo: add more symbols
Default : "$"
```

Comment: I don't have Euro symbol on my keyboard. so can you suggest me any alternate method ?

Comment: Copy it from my answer.  I found it by using the Character Map application (Start | All Programs | Accessories | System Tools).

Comment: That worked ..Thnx. But euro was just an example. I want to create report where I will be converting currencies from Dollar to Euro/Pound/INR/... So I want code that will dynamically add the currency symbols.